# Detecting faces that are looking into the webcam

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, face-detection

I'm currently doing a face detection in Java/JavaCV.
So far I've been experimenting with the code.

I'm using this face cascade = haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml

I've got this code below for Detecting largest face found in the webcam

```
CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, classifier, storage, 1.1, 1,                           
                           CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT);
```

My first question is:
Since this is only detecting one face - the largest face found in the webcam
is this the correct way to do it to detect multiple faces?

```
CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img, classifier, storage, 1.1, 1, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
```

My second question is:
Is it possible to detect faces that are only looking into the webcam? and those that are not looking into the wbecam?
So the it will detect faces but I want to set some sort of scores - so let's say 1 is for faces that are looking into the webcam and 2 - for faces that are looking away from the webcam? How do I proceed to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If a person looks directly, his/her eye should be perpendicular(if he/she doesn't have an eye problem :P).

This theory suggests, **pupil and iris should be circular** and not elliptical if a person looks directly.
Please note that I meant by the visible part of pupil and iris only.

Answer (score 0):

Most face detection lib are trained toward people facing the camera since this isa major constraint for face recognition. This being said, Haar cascade can be trained also to detect profile or even focusing on eyes and nose (ie part of face).

I didn't use javaCV myself but tested openIMAJ (which rocks for me!) which can reuse openCV configuration file (as far as I understood). In the source of their face detection library, you will find models for profile and eye detection.